# Allow message inspection by proxy without ability to modify it

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

My client creates a private/public key pair and sends it securely to a server (the "public" key is not really public, only the server is supposed to know it). The server then sends messages to the client, encrypted using the public key.

Now a customer wants to add a proxy that inspects these messages. Obviously the proxy cannot inspect the encrypted message, only the client. Can anyone think of a way to allow the proxy to verify that the encrypted message is what it is supposed to be, without being able to replace it with it's own encrypted message? We assume that traffic from server to proxy is secure (both are on the same machine).

(We are willing to modify what the server sends out. I am writing the client, and there's no way I'll hand the private key to anyone, and the server devs are *very* unwilling to pass the public key to anyone. Otherwise they could pass the public key and the plaintext message to the proxy and let it create the encrypted message itself).

Comment: What do you mean with "the proxy verifies the message"? If that requires looking into the message, the proxy needs some way to do so (e.g. decrypt). If the proxy runs on the same machine as the server, verifying the origin of the message isn't really interesting (just use a local port, no need to go over the network).

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone think of a way to allow the proxy to verify that the encrypted message is what it is supposed to be, without being able to replace it with it's own encrypted message?"

The standard solution is for the server to have its own public/private signature keypair.  The server's public key is given to the proxy and the client in some secure way (that is, in a way that the proxy knows that it is the correct key - we don't care about privacy here).  Then, when the server generates an encrypted message, the server signs it using his private key, and the proxy (who has the server's public key) verify the signature (using his copy of the public key).  Then, when the client gets the encrypted message, he also verifies the signature (to check that the proxy has not modified the message).

You may also need to include something to allow the client to detect if the proxy replaced an encrypted message with a previous encrypted signed message (which would pass the signature check); perhaps a time stamp or a sequence number that always increases.

Can this work in your scenario?